# How to send Astar using Python(SubstrateInterface)

Tags: astar

I want to automate sending astar(NOT EVM) with Python(SubstrateInterface). I received an error when executing the following code.

```python
    # Imports
    from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface, Keypair, KeypairType
    from substrateinterface.exceptions import SubstrateRequestException
    
    # Construct the API provider
    substrate = SubstrateInterface(
        url="wss://rpc.astar.network",
        ss58_format=42,
        type_registry_preset='substrate-node-template',
    )
    
    keypair = Keypair.create_from_mnemonic(
        "***",
        ss58_format = 42,
    )
    print(keypair.ss58_address)
    
    # Form a transaction call
    call = substrate.compose_call(
        call_module='Balances',
        call_function="transfer",
        call_params={
            "dest": "***",
            'value': 1 * 10**16,
            "gas_limit": 21000,
         }
    )
    
    # Form a signed extrinsic
    extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(
        call = call,
        keypair = keypair,
        nonce = substrate.get_account_nonce(keypair.ss58_address),
    )
    print(extrinsic)
    
    # Submit the extrinsic
    try:
        receipt = substrate.submit_extrinsic(
            extrinsic,
            wait_for_inclusion = True,
        )
        print("Extrinsic '{}' sent and included in block '{}'".format(receipt.extrinsic_hash, receipt.block_hash))
    except SubstrateRequestException as e:
        print("Failed to send: {}".format(e))
```

> Failed to send: { 'code': 1002, 'message': 'Verification Error:
> Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm
> trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\n\n
> 0: 0x44fa8a - !rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x3922e4 -
> !core::panicking::panic_fmt::h32de9c76c9d5eb0c\n    2:
> 0x1e31a5 - !TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction\n',
> 'data': 'RuntimeApi("Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap:
> wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM
> backtrace:\n\n    0: 0x44fa8a - !rust_begin_unwind\n    1:
> 0x3922e4 - !core::panicking::panic_fmt::h32de9c76c9d5eb0c\n
> 2: 0x1e31a5 -
> !TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction\n")' }

What could be the issue?

Comment: I think it's due to the issue of Astar's implementation. It's better to create the issue to let them know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This source code works.

### command

```
% python3 test.py
/Users/shin.takahashi/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py:34: NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
  warnings.warn(
5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
{'account_id': '0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d', 'signature': {'Sr25519': '0x183aada62201ad0a84b1c08212f64dfb266cc678d41d5f60f68cafaeb052ae3e52c57e8c590b1049e56047bfbf5d594784e27604f7b76b77fe8ec196844a2488'}, 'call_function': 'transfer', 'call_module': 'Balances', 'call_args': {'dest': 'ZfQqz2FPet1fD9yqokjiPy2Uzk3EakwQdKyBVFdfTrgVe8E', 'value': 10000000000000000}, 'nonce': 3, 'era': '00', 'tip': 0, 'asset_id': {'tip': 0, 'asset_id': None}, 'signature_version': 1, 'address': '0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d', 'call': {'call_function': 'transfer', 'call_module': 'Balances', 'call_args': {'dest': 'ZfQqz2FPet1fD9yqokjiPy2Uzk3EakwQdKyBVFdfTrgVe8E', 'value': 10000000000000000}}}
Extrinsic '0x00a6386e01e3915fa5c89f913163ef6eac360521bcb3f35568b44d55fb485215' sent and included in block '0x9ab42000c6fdcfe2512ef3fd21f227e277fe51df33684f5592d5a43cb742373e'
```

### source code

% cat test.py

```
# Imports
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface, Keypair, KeypairType
from substrateinterface.exceptions import SubstrateRequestException

# Construct the API provider
substrate = SubstrateInterface(
    url="ws://127.0.0.1:9944",
#    ss58_format=42,
#    type_registry_preset='substrate-node-template',
)

#keypair = Keypair.create_from_mnemonic(
#    "*******",
#    ss58_format = 42,
#)
keypair = Keypair.create_from_uri('//Alice')

print(keypair.ss58_address)

# Form a transaction call
call = substrate.compose_call(
    call_module='Balances',
    call_function="transfer",
    call_params={
        "dest": "ZfQqz2FPet1fD9yqokjiPy2Uzk3EakwQdKyBVFdfTrgVe8E",
        'value': 1 * 10**16,
#        "gas_limit": 21000000000,
     }
)

# Form a signed extrinsic
extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(
    call = call,
    keypair = keypair,
#    nonce = substrate.get_account_nonce(keypair.ss58_address),
)
print(extrinsic)

# Submit the extrinsic
try:
    receipt = substrate.submit_extrinsic(
        extrinsic,
        wait_for_inclusion = True,
    )
    print("Extrinsic '{}' sent and included in block '{}'".format(receipt.extrinsic_hash, receipt.block_hash))
except SubstrateRequestException as e:
    print("Failed to send: {}".format(e))
```

Comment: Your code worked well. Furthermore, even when I changed the url to mainnet and rewrote it to generate the key pair from mnemonic, it still worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when using Go api

https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client

I am currently using on the latest version `4.1.0`

My node version: `polkadot-v0.9.43`

Issue:

> Verification Error: Runtime error: Execution failed: Execution aborted
> due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed WASM
> backtrace: error while executing at wasm backtrace:
> 0: 0x579efd - !rust_begin_unwind
> 1: 0xe402 - !core::panicking::panic_fmt::he4489d678d6570d5
> 2: 0x13b4c1 - !TaggedTransactionQueue_validate_transaction

My example code:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v4/signature"
    "github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v4/types"
    //"github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v4/rpc/author"
    gsrpc "github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v4"


)

func main(){
    //Alice account 
    nemo := "0xe5be9a5092b81bca64be81d212e7f2f9eba183bb7a90954f7b76361f6edb5c0a";

    api, err:= gsrpc.NewSubstrateAPI("wss://shibuya-rpc.dwellir.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can not connect blockchain")
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected")
    keypair, err := signature.KeyringPairFromSecret(nemo, 5)
    fmt.Println("keypair", keypair.Address, keypair.PublicKey, keypair.URI)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("keypair", err)
    }
    meta, err := api.RPC.State.GetMetadataLatest()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("MEta", err)
    }
    // fmt.Println("Meta:",meta)
    c, err := types.NewCall(meta, "Balances.transfer","5FLSigC9HGRKVhB9FiEo4Y3koPsNmBmLJbpXg2mp1hXcS59Y", types.NewUCompactFromUInt(10000))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("New call", err)
    }

    ext := types.NewExtrinsic(c)

    era := types.ExtrinsicEra{IsImmortalEra: false}

    genesisHash ,err := api.RPC.Chain.GetBlockHash(0)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Genesis hash", err)
    }
    rv, err := api.RPC.State.GetRuntimeVersionLatest()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Runtime version", err)
    }

    key, err := types.CreateStorageKey(meta, "System", "Account", keypair.PublicKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Storage Key", err)
    }

    var accountInfo types.AccountInfo
    ok, err := api.RPC.State.GetStorageLatest(key, &accountInfo)
    fmt.Println("OK", ok)
    nonce := uint32(accountInfo.Nonce)
    o := types.SignatureOptions{
        // BlockHash:   blockHash,
        BlockHash:          genesisHash, // BlockHash needs to == GenesisHash if era is immortal. // TODO: add an error?
        Era:                era,
        GenesisHash:        genesisHash,
        Nonce:              types.NewUCompactFromUInt(uint64(nonce)),
        SpecVersion:        rv.SpecVersion,
        Tip:                types.NewUCompactFromUInt(0),
        TransactionVersion: rv.TransactionVersion,
    }
    err = ext.Sign(keypair, o)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Sign", err)
    }

    txnHash, err := api.RPC.Author.SubmitAndWatchExtrinsic(ext)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("submit", err)
        
    }   

    fmt.Println("after submission txnHash", txnHash)


}
```